# Can I replace a laptop keyboard with one of a different key layout?

Tags: laptop, keyboard

I have a Lenovo G530 and I broke its internal keyboard (I don't think I can repair the matrix). I want to replace it with a new one, but it will have a different key layout (Enter, Shift and keys around). It is for the same model but my laptop has the European layout or whatever they call it... Will the new keyboard work? 
[Old_new_keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jm7Rh.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Since it is for the same computer, it should work fine as long as the ribbon is the same.

If anything changes (besides the keyboard obviously) it might be the drivers for the keyboard

Comment: and you'd be able to get the drivers from Lenovo's support site